# How to find all lines in a set that coincide in a single point?

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

Suppose I am given a set of lines, how can I partition this set into a number of clusters, such that all the lines in each cluster coincide in a single point?

Comment: Is it a computing question? What language do you use?

Comment: No. An algorithmic/Analytic question. Anyway I use MATLAB.

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more detail. Are these lines (ie infinite length), or line segments? If for example you had 3 line segments, being the edges of a triangle, what should the clusters be?

Comment: Thanks.
1. They are lines (infnite), 2. That won't happen.

Comment: when you have 3 non-parallel infinite lines then how is that not forming a triangle? btw may be a better word would be intersect instead of coincide unless I miss something in translation

Answer (score 0):

If number of lines N is reasonable, then you can use O(N^3) algorithm:
for ever pair of lines (in form `A*x+B*y+C=0`) check whether they intersect - exclude pairs of parallel and not-coincident lines with determinant

```
|A1 B1|
        = 0 
|A2 B2|
```

For every intersecting pair if another line shares the same intersecting point, with determinant:

```
|A1 B1 C1|
|A2 B2 C2| = 0 
|A3 B3 C3|
```

If N is too large for cubic algorithm using, then calculate all intersection points (upto O(N^2) of them) and add these points to any map structure (hashtable, for example). Check for matching points. Don't forget about numerical errors issue.